# Create a pattern along the bottom edge of a view

Tags: android, android-view

I would like to have a pattern along the edge of a view. For this particular case, I would like it to be a jagged edge (like tearing parchment paper or tinfoil out of a roll). I would prefer a more general solution - perhaps at some point I would like waves along the top of a view, or a binder coil down the side. I would prefer to have some kind of repeating image rather than stretching an image.

**Edit:**

I would like a the pattern to occur just around the edge of the view (perhaps only on one edge). For example, a tear mark on the bottom or top of a receipt. The tear should not repeat up or down the image, just at the bottom edge.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `drawable` (`pattern_tile.xml`) with the root element of a `<bitmap>`. Like this for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bgnoise_lg"
    android:tileMode="repeat" >

</bitmap>
```

And the drawable image used in the code above is:

[image]

Then, in your XML, you set it like you set the usual background using this attribute:

```
android:background="@drawable/pattern_tile"
```

Oh. Almost forgot, I put these two files, in the `drawable-nodpi` folder. I don't want Android to ever scale the image for me.

Obviously, since your question is a little vague, you will have to use your own image instead of the example I have posted, play around with it a bit till you get the result that suits your needs.

**NOTE:** Such a thing is *typically* done when you have patterns that should repeat instead of filling up the screen or stretching. So make sure the image you use is such a pattern that can repeat and not look out of place.

Comment: This creates a tiled background over the entire image. I will update the question to clarify more.